# Как отфильтровать массив?

Tags: javascript

```
for ( let i = 0; i < cell.length; i ++ ) {
    for ( let x = 0 ; x < arr1.length; x++ ) {
        if ( cell[i] === arr1[x] ) {
            console.log(cell[i])
        }
    }
}
```

У меня есть 2 массива. В первом ( cell ) находятся 180 div элементов во втором ( 
 arr 1 )  22 div`а. При такой фильтрации находятся равные div элементы, но мне надо найти не равные, то есть элементы массива cell которые не равны элементам массива arr1. !== не работает Как это можно реализовать ? Заранее спасибо !

Comment: http://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Интересно, прочему заминусовали? нормальный вопрос. Как сделать array difference в js

Comment: @nick_n_a я думаю, что он просто собрал со страницы одни и те же элементы, но разными селекторами. А если так, то они легко сравниваются

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Если коротко, то я создал div элементы ( массив cell ) задал им атрибуты posx и posy через цикл, отфильтровал по осям x и y нужные мне элементы и получил массив arr1, и как мне подсказали создал новый массив arr2 равный разнице cell и arr1 и рандомному элементу arr2 задал нужный класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в лоб, то так

```js
for (let i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
  let found = false;
  for (let x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {
    if (cell[i] === arr1[x]) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    console.log(cell[i])
  }
}
```